# Link jira issue to one bitbucket repository

Tags: git, bitbucket, jira

I'm working on a post receive hook where i'm testing if my commit messages equals an existent Jira issue . The problem i have is that i need to put a constraint on the use of jira issues, they should be used with only one repository in other words if i have an issue called "test-1" used in repository "ProjectA" this issue should not be used in another repository. Is there a way to that ?